# Me->VPN->Tor->Socks5->Tor: Where would a honeypot do the most damage?

Tags: vpn, whonix, encryption

Since most vpn's are untrustworthy, and Tor exit nodes can be hosted by malicious entities, im trying to create a trustless chain of anonymization and encryption. I feel as there might be flaws in my setup because of my lack of understanding of the technical aspects of packet encryption. Im looking for criticism of those with more understanding. Setup is as follows

VPN on host OS  ->  VM#1 Whonix Gateway VM(Tor)  ->  VM#2 OS that has all traffic forced through Tor by Whonix Gateway, then use proxifier to connect to socks5 proxy  -> Tor browser

Can my vpn see my traffic at the end of the chain?

Comment: This proposed setup is less secure and less anonymous than Tor.